# Laravel: Calling to post method function from the same controller in route

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.3

I have three functions in my controller.One of them is `GET` type and other two is `POST` type. One `POST` type is working well but how can i call the second `POST` method from Route?

i am calling my functions from route like this and they are working well

```
Route::get('/conference/home', 'ViewController@index');
Route::post('/conference/home','ViewController@showBooking');
```

there is another function for Deleting from database which is a post method type. Say the Name of that Function is `DeletingRecord()`. How can i call this function from Route?

Comment: Use the method field so you can use patch and delete requests.

Answer (score 4):

Some considerations:

1. A controller method is not inherently a POST or GET method. It's the router that decides how to handle a POST or GET request.
2. If you must use a POST request to delete a record then you must assign it to a different route name. Each route will resolve to exactly one method. For example:

   ```
   Route::get('/conference/home', 'ViewController@index');
   Route::post('/conference/home','ViewController@showBooking');
   Route::post('/conference/delete','ViewController@DeletingRecord');
   ```
3. There's no reason why you can't use the DELETE method for this:

   ```
   Route::get('/conference/home', 'ViewController@index');
   Route::post('/conference/home','ViewController@showBooking');
   Route::delete('/conference/home','ViewController@DeletingRecord');
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use delete HTTP verb.

then your code will look like this:

```
Route::get('/conference/home', 'ViewController@index');
Route::post('/conference/home','ViewController@showBooking');
Route::delete('/conference/home','ViewController@DeletingRecord');
```

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_Web_services
- http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use single routing line instead of more routing line as following:

```
Route::resource('conference', 'ViewController');
```

for reference please see following link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers

i hope its help you